# PHP compare a given datetime with current datetime

Tags: php, datetime

I have a problem comparing a customized php datetime with current datetime, the code is below:

```
$requestDate = new DateTime("2014-05-28 11:14:00");
$nowDate = new DateTime();

$aklTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland");
$requestDate->setTimezone($aklTimeZone);
$nowDate->setTimezone($aklTimeZone);
echo $nowDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if ($requestDate > $nowDate) {
  echo '1';
} else if($requestDate == $nowDate){
  echo '0';
} else{
  echo "-1";
}
```

The printed result is:

```
2014-05-28 12:21:31

1
```

The $requestDate is supposed to be less than the $nowDate, how come it is greater here?

Thank you

Comment: The request date is clearly in the future (at least it is for me)

Comment: i dont know what time in your place is, but it will certainly echo `1` on my time too

Comment: What is timezone of this time `"2014-05-28 11:14:00"`?

Comment: You might want to check what `$requestDate` becomes **after** you've applied the timezone change. I recommend using the *r* format, eg `$date->format('r')`